# Solving a steady flow in a subdomain of a mesh using FiPy

Tags: subdomain, fipy

I'm fairly new to FiPy and I'm currently facing an issue of which I am sure can be solved easily: I want to solve a 3D steady flow of the form:

```
    eq = ( DiffusionTerm(var=u) ==  -(1/mu) * dP + g_acc * (rho/mu) * ymax )
```

Where velocity u is in the y-direction and where du/dy = 0.
I would like to let the PDE solve within a subdomain of the entire 3D mesh, meaning that:

- 0 <= X < Boundary_1,  u=0.
- Boundary_1 <= X < Boundary_2, u = PDE solution
- Boundary_2 <= X < Lx, u = 0.

Currently I have tried the following:

```
mesh = Grid3D(dx=dx, dy=dy, dz=dz, Lx=(Lx-0), Ly =(ymax-ymin), Lz=(zmax-zmin))
u = CellVariable(name = "velocity", mesh = mesh)

X, Y, Z = mesh.cellCenters
LeftWall = (X <= xBoundary_left)
RightWall = (X > xBoundary_right)
FrontWall = (mesh.facesFront)
BackWall = (mesh.facesBack)

u.constrain(0., where=LeftWall)
u.constrain(0., where=RightWall)
u.constrain(0., where=FrontWall)
u.constrain(0., where=BackWall)
```

Which leads to a solution of image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YiBW.png) (see attached image). The boundary conditions for the X variable are not taken into account as I would like, as you can see in the example in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yCR0.png), where only the PDE domain is shown.
What I am looking for is a way to define the boundary conditions at the faces of the subdomain in such a way that it does not 'crop' the solution, but rather only solves the PDE for that subdomain. If it is possible to 'stitch' meshes together that include a Cellvariable u that has value 0 for two meshes and the value of the solved PDE for one mesh, that would be great as well!

I have tried working with inner boundary conditions in the form of an Implicit source, but that ended up in different errors.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

FiPy constraints do not work on internal faces.

In our own work, rather than only solving an equation in a subdomain, we modify the coefficients to cause different behaviors to dominate in different subdomains. Conservation of momentum and conservation of mass don't suddenly stop being true; rather different conditions lead to, e.g., different Reynolds numbers.

It is possible to solve different equations on different meshes and communicate between them. See, e.g.,

- https://www.mail-archive.com/search?q=how+to+set+up+data+transfer+between+two+adjacent+nonuniform+meshs&l=fipy%40nist.gov
- [How to extract a plane from a 3D variable in FiPy (3D to 2D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863958/how-to-extract-a-plane-from-a-3d-variable-in-fipy-3d-to-2d)
- https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=fipy%40nist.gov&q=How+to+combine+scipy.interpolate.interp2d+with+fipy+variables&x=0&y=0
- https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=fipy%40nist.gov&q=Spline+interpolation+and+fipy+variable&x=18&y=9